# Oracle update statement with analytics is failing

Tags: oracle, sql-update, window-functions

The Table_B contains duplicate records as seen below. What I am trying to do is lookup Table_A using Table_B.SERIAL_NUM and update Table_A .COVERAGE_END coloumn with the most recent Date value in COVERAGE_TO coloumn in Table_B.

### Table_B

```
SERIAL_NUM  ,COVERAGE_FROM  ,COVERAGE_TO 
123456  ,26/12/2014 ,13/12/2015
123456  ,14/12/2015 ,13/12/2016
23456   ,18/12/2014 ,13/12/2015
23456   ,14/12/2015 ,13/12/2016
```

Following is the update statement I am using.

```
update Table_A J
set ( J.COVERAGE_END_DATE)
=(select COVERAGE_TO from 
(
select SERIAL_NUM, COVERAGE_TO, row_number() over(partition by SERIAL_NUM order by COVERAGE_TO desc) as rn from  TABLE_B B

)where rn = 1
)
where exists
(
select * from TABLE_B Q where Q.SERIAL_NUM = J.SERIAL_NUMBER
)
;
```

However I get the following error

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Can Some one please help me with this Query?

Comment: Why partition on B at all (which would require a top(1))? Why not just get max(coverage_to) from B directly?

Comment: as you can see the serial numbers are repeating in Table B. So for a particular SN I need the most recent date from Table B. Then i need to update Table A with that date. Table As serial number is a unique value.  I am not an expert in Oracle, if you can show me how I can achieve the same your way, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compare J's SERIAL_NUMBER with B's to get the only proper value.

```
 where rn = 1 and J.SERIAL_NUMBER = SERIAL_NUM
```

If not, subquery will return max values for every SERIAL_NUM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why partitioning is needed here.
Would a simple MAX() not produce the needed result?

```
update table_a
   set coverage_end_date = (
     select max(coverage_to)
       from table_b b inner join table_a a on b.serial_num = a.serial_num
   )
;
```